# How do you extend Linq to SQL?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Last year, Scott Guthrie [stated](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx) “You can actually override the raw SQL that LINQ to SQL uses if you want absolute control over the SQL executed”, but I can’t find documentation describing an extensibility method.

I would like to modify the following LINQ to SQL query:

```
using (NorthwindContext northwind = new NorthwindContext ()) {
    var q = from row in northwind.Customers
            let orderCount = row.Orders.Count ()
            select new {
                row.ContactName,
                orderCount
            };
}
```

Which results in the following TSQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[ContactName], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[CustomerID] = [t0].[CustomerID]
    ) AS [orderCount]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
```

To:

```
using (NorthwindContext northwind = new NorthwindContext ()) {
    var q = from row in northwind.Customers.With (
                        TableHint.NoLock, TableHint.Index (0))
            let orderCount = row.Orders.With (
                        TableHint.HoldLock).Count ()
            select new {
                row.ContactName,
                orderCount
            };
}
```

Which *would* result in the following TSQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[ContactName], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [t1] WITH (HOLDLOCK)
    WHERE [t1].[CustomerID] = [t0].[CustomerID]
    ) AS [orderCount]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0] WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX(0))
```

Using:

```
public static Table<TEntity> With<TEntity> (
    this Table<TEntity> table,
    params TableHint[] args) where TEntity : class {

    //TODO: implement
    return table;
}
public static EntitySet<TEntity> With<TEntity> (
    this EntitySet<TEntity> entitySet,
    params TableHint[] args) where TEntity : class {

    //TODO: implement
    return entitySet;
}
```

And

```
public class TableHint {
    //TODO: implement
    public static TableHint NoLock;
    public static TableHint HoldLock;
    public static TableHint Index (int id) {
        return null;
    }
    public static TableHint Index (string name) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using some type of LINQ to SQL extensibility, other than [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/archive/2008/05/04/mocks-nix-an-extensible-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx). Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ability to change the underlying provider and thus modify the SQL did not make the final cut in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: I was on the LINQ to SQL dev team :)  If you want to modify some specific operations you can use the technique described here http://damieng.com/blog/2009/04/12/linq-to-sql-tips-and-tricks-2 but there is no extensibility model/provider mechanism that is publicly supported.

Comment: Not sure how it happened, but the above goes to an error page because Damien's link changed by one day: https://damieng.com/blog/2009/04/13/linq-to-sql-tips-and-tricks-2/

Comment: Oops sorry, I changed blog engine and it looks like it now honors timezones :D

Answer (score -1):

`DataContext x = new DataContext`

Something like this perhaps?

`var a = x.Where().with()`...etc

It lets you have a much finer control over the SQL.

Comment: Even if this does work, doesn't `var a = x.Where()...` mean that you have already performed a `select` and therefore have records that you should not have queried in the first place?