# NOLOCK with Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is it possible to get Linq2Sql to emit a NOLOCK in its SQL? And if so, how?

Comment: Just found this question which crosses over in part, but credit due anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963/how-do-you-extend-linq-to-sql

I'll keep the question open for a while just in case.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes it is, so here's the entry [from my blog](http://www.madprops.org/blog/linq-to-sql-and-nolock-hints/):

> The NOLOCK hint is essentially the
>   same as wrapping a query in a
>   transaction whose "isolation level" is
>   set to "read uncommitted". It means
>   that the query doesn't care if stuff
>   is in the process of being written to
>   the rows it's reading from - it'll
>   read that "dirty" data and return it
>   as part of the result set.
>
> Turns out that you can do the whole
>   "read uncommitted" transaction thing
>   using the old System.Transactions
>   namespace introduced in .NET 2.0.
>   Here's some sample code:
>
> ```
> using (var txn = new TransactionScope(
>     TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
>     new TransactionOptions
>     {
>         IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
>     }
> ))
> {
>     // Your LINQ to SQL query goes here
> }
> ```
>
> So I'm creating a new TransactionScope
>   object and telling it to use a
>   read-uncommitted isolation level. The
>   query within the "using" statement now
>   acts as if all its tables were reading
>   with the NOLOCK hint.

Here are the first results from a Google search for "linq sql nolock":

[InfoQ: Implementing NOLOCK with LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/linq-nolock)

[Matt Hamilton - LINQ to SQL and NOLOCK Hints : Mad Props!](http://www.madprops.org/blog/linq-to-sql-and-nolock-hints/)

[Scott Hanselman's Computer Zen - Getting LINQ to SQL and LINQ to ...](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx)

Comment: If I wanted to be totally correct, none of these options actually "emit a NOLOCK" in the SQL itself - they use the transaction's isolation setting instead. Same thing, but not technically what the question asked.

Comment: Copied the text from your blog, so that nobody has to click-through links to get to the answer.

Comment: No worries. My main point was that this stuff is easily discoverable on Google without having to ask here. This question will probably usurp the #1 place on Google for this search now. :)

Comment: @Matt: That's the point! Create a canonical source! See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions/8729#8729

Comment: Yeah I dunno if I wholly agree with that idea. For me, Scott's or my blog post was the canonical source for that answer. I don't know if my stealing content from others' blogs (or even mine) is the right approach.

Comment: Would have to aggree with Matt on the content stealing.  Matt took the time to write the post on his blog.  Now SOF is getting the traffic

Comment: You can't upvote and downvote answers on a blog and so there is no way to vet the quality over there.  I think copying short snippets to SO with attribution is the right way to go.

Comment: Well, the real answer is that you cannot use nolock hint with linqtosql. Hanselman alos wrote about this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx

Comment: Is there any reason to keep a reference to the variable `txn`?  Do you have to pass the reference to your context?

Comment: @Drew Good point. I don't believe there is any need for the `txn` variable. Been a long time since I've played with this stuff - it'd be worth testing yourself.

Comment: Ahhhh... performance relief.  To what address do a send the pizza's and t-shirts?

Comment: In my case, TransactionScope has raise some COMException: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130767/the-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remote-network-transactions

Comment: You omitted the `txn.Complete();`. Was that on purpose? I see that it works without it, but I'm told it's needed. Perhaps you can answer my question [Do I need “transactionScope.Complete();”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53657509/939213).

Answer (score 26):

Further to theKing's [LinqPad `My Extensions` addition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873661/256431):

```
public static IQueryable<T> DumpNoLock<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    using (var txn = GetNewReadUncommittedScope())
    {
        return query.Dump();
    }   
}

public static System.Transactions.TransactionScope GetNewReadUncommittedScope()
{
    return new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(
        System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
        new System.Transactions.TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
        });
}
public static IQueryable<T> DumpNoLock<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string description)
{
    using (var txn = GetNewReadUncommittedScope())
    {
        return query.Dump(description);
    }   
}

public static List<T> ToListNoLock<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    using (var txn = GetNewReadUncommittedScope())
    {
        return query.ToList();
    }   
}

public static U NoLock<T,U>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<IQueryable<T>,U> expr)
{
    using (var txn = GetNewReadUncommittedScope())
    {
        return expr(query);
    }   
}
```

The last one means you can do a `NOLOCK` on any evaluating queries you haven't a `NoLock` explicitly written for (like I've got for `ToListNoLock` above). So, for example:

```
somequery.NoLock((x)=>x.Count()).Dump();
```

will evaluate the query with `NOLOCK`.

Note that you have to ensure you're evaluating the query. E.g. `.NoLock((x)=>x.Distinct()).Count().Dump()` won't do anything usefully different from `.Distinct().Count().Dump()`.

Answer (score 11):

A simple way may be to run a command on your DataContext class

```
using (var dataContext = new DataContext())
{
  dataContext.ExecuteCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");

  // Your SQL query
}
```

Comment: Maybe this answer embedded with theKings answer will be a nice to have

Answer (score 9):

Here is an extension method to use with LINQPAD

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Dump2<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
{
    using (var txn = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
        new TransactionOptions
        {       
            IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
        }))
    {
        return query.Dump();
    }   
}
```

Then you can call it as:

```
MyTable.Where(t => t.Title = "Blah").Dump2();
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, Entity Framework 5 (based on @Soppus answer):

```
private FoobarEntities db = new FoobarEntities();
public FoobarController()
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution avoid the "COMException: The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions." that may append on other requests.