# The Partner transacttion manager has disabled it support for remote/network transaction(Exception from HRESULT : 0x8004D025)

Tags: c#

I get the following exception when I connect my application to the remote data base and there is no exception when I connect my application to the local database. What is the problem?

I also have searched my problem in www.google.com. I have found many solution and I follow those instruction that are written in solutions but still I face the same problem.
The Exception is given below:

> "The Partner transacttion manager has disabled it support for
>   remote/network transaction(Exception from HRESULT : 0x8004D025)".

Comment: It sounds like you have to talk to the DBA of the remote database and ask him to *enable* support for remote transactions.

Comment: This has already been answered in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130767/the-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remote-network-transactions)

Comment: Mokchhya in that thread the problem of ASP.Net is solved and i am using pure C#.Net.