# Insert into multiple tables using WCF Transactions

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, wcf, transactions

I am trying to add an entry into a table and use the primary key of that added entry to create an additional entry into another table.

The error I am getting is

> The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network
>   transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D024)

I believe this is caused by creating multiple connections within a single TransactionScope, but I am doing everything within one context / using statement, so I do not believe that I should be receiving this error.

**Service**

```
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    public void CreateGroup(NewGroupData data)
    {
        var groupRepo = _GroupRepo ?? new InvestigatorGroupRepository();
        groupRepo.CreateGroup(data.UserId, data.InvestigatorGroupName, data.HasGameAssignment, data.InstitutionId);

    }
```

**Repository**

```
   public void CreateGroup(string userId, string investigatorGroupName, bool hasGameAssignment, int institutionId)
    {
        using (var context = new GameDbContext())
        {
            var newGroup = new InvestigatorGroup()
            {
                InvestigatorGroupName = investigatorGroupName,
                HasGameAssignment = hasGameAssignment,
                InstitutionId = institutionId,
                IsTrashed = false
            };

            int institutionUserId =
                context.InstitutionUsers.Where(
                    iu => !iu.IsTrashed && iu.APUser.UserId == userId && iu.InstitutionId == institutionId).Select(iu => iu.InstitutionUserId).Single();

            var newGroupUser = new InvestigatorGroupUser()
            {
                InstitutionUserId = institutionUserId,
                InvestigatorGroup = newGroup,
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            context.InvestigatorGroupUsers.Add(newGroupUser);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with a wrong assumption.

The line...

```
int newGroupId = context.InvestigatorGroups.Add(newGroup).InvestigatorGroupId;
```

...will always assign 0 to `newGroupId`. The `Add` method only marks the entity for insert, but doesn't actually insert it. Only `SaveChanges` writes data to the database, not any other method in Entity Framework.

So the assignment...

```
InvestigatorGroupId = newGroupId,
```

...is faulty as well. You have to assign the new `InvestigatorGroup` to a navigation property in `InvestigatorGroupUser`:

```
InvestigatorGroup = newGroup,
```

Add this navigation property to `InvestigatorGroupUser` if you haven't got it yet.

If you have that, it's enough to execute these lines:

```
context.InvestigatorGroupUsers.Add(newGroupUser);
context.SaveChanges();
```

No need to `Add` the `newGroup` object too, It will be added by adding `newGroupUser`.

So if you do that, the only transaction you need is the one that `SaveChanges` uses internally by default. For the code you show, you don't need a `TransactionScope`. If this is part of a greater WCF transaction the story may be different, but I think at least you needed some misconceptions to be straightened out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I made the changes you've said but I still get the same error (see my updated question). I have kept the transactionscope because if the insert to InvestigatorGroupUser fails I want the insert into InvestigatorGroup to fail as well

Comment: The point is that you don't need the TransactionScope. `SaveChanges` does *all inserts* in one transaction it start and commits itself.

Comment: While @GertArnold is correct and the transaction is unnecessary in this case, I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130767/the-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remote-network-transactions will explain how to fix this error if you encounter it in a context where this is required.

Comment: I removed the TransactionScope and it now works thanks! Just out of curiosity, how come I get an error when I keep the TransactionScope? I don't believe it is due to DTC as I have another operation that uses TransactionScope and does not generate an error

Comment: I don't know. Your question didn't show where the TransactionScope started and what else happened within its scope. Only wrapping the code you show in a TransactionScope shouldn't make a difference (although it wouldn't be necessary).

Comment: @EitanK it depends on what that other transactionscope is doing. DTC may be enabled, but is DTC network access enabled? Perhaps the other scope doesn't need the network access.