# Deadlock on Linq to Entity Framework Core 2.0 Table

Tags: linq, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-core

I'm getting what I think to be a deadlock when trying to run a bunch of linq queries in parallel.

I am running a `Task.WhenAll()` on this method:

```
public async Task<MetabuildScan> GetLatestMetabuildScanAsync(string buildId)
{
    var metabuildScanStatuses = new[] { "Completed", "Referenced" };

    // Get the latest metabuild scan for this image build
    var latestScan = await (from scan in _qsaContext.MetabuildScans
                           where scan.SoftwareImageBuildId == buildId
                           && metabuildScanStatuses.Contains(scan.SIScanStatus)
                           orderby scan.SIScanStartedOn descending
                           select scan).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // If there is a related scan, then use that one, else, use the one we just got
    var latestCompletedScanId = latestScan?.RelatedScanId ?? latestScan?.Id;

    return await _qsaContext.MetabuildScans
                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(scan => scan.Id == latestCompletedScanId);
}
```

I am getting a `System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`

`_qsaContext` was created using Entity-Framework Core.

At first, I thought the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` would fix my issue (I had a non-asynchronous `FirstOrDefault` in there at first), but it didn't.

I'm wondering what the best solution to get around this deadlock would be. The table I am selecting from is a large table, so I can't pull the whole table into memory.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, wrap your query in try/catch and repeat your transaction.

Comment: That catches the exception but it doesn't solve my problem. Updating answer with the exception in hopes that it helps.

Comment: Some time it is hard to avoid deadlocks in large multithread/multiprocess systems.
Catch and re-try is the simplest solution. Another way is to use NOLOCK.

Comment: If catching and retrying is the only solution then there is no point in having this code be asynchronous. Catching and retrying will also add a lot of overhead with all of the retry attempts. This method I am working with is run almost always on 10 different threads at the same time. That's a lot of overhead.

Comment: Is NOLOCK with LINQ a good solution? I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220807/nolock-with-linq-to-sql but the solutions don't look clean, they look like hacks.

Comment: The DB does not care about sync/async calls. It received requests and the deadlock just happened. Async is the right way to go if you have many threads and you want your OS to start/exec/finish more threads at a time.
Try/catch does not add any additional expensive overhead to your code. Repeating transaction may not a good solution for banks where data may change in quick way.
In you case you work with some queue stored in a table. So, it should be fine.

Comment: NOLOCK is the same as READ_UNCOMMIT. I usually do not recommend it. But if you want to try then there should be like this:
```
using (var tr = _qsaContext.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommit))
{
  // your EF LINQ here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework DbContext is not thread safe.  You can't run parallel queries against it like you are attempting to do.

If you need to have a shared context for your queries that you'll need to await each one individually and sequentially.

If they don't need a shared context but do need to run in parallel then you'll need to have a separate context for each query.

If using a DI framework, perhaps you can look into making your DbContext Transient (instead of what I'm assuming is Scoped) and injecting that into a query class that will call your query methods.